# C++ C4996 error with _wfopen function

Tags: c++, file

I have 4 header files, all of them open data from a txt file with _wfopen(), like below:

```
FILE* file = _wfopen(L"data.txt",L"r,ccs=utf-8");
```

VC++ gives me an error C4996 but in one header file only, the other three have no error at all. How can I fix this ? 
UPDATE:
My professor gave me this code.I compiled it and there's only C4996 warning.Since I need to reuse it, I created a new project and copy everything in his code into the new project.Then it gave me a C4996 error.

Comment: C4996 is supposed to be a warning, typically harmless if you know what you're doing. Use `#pragma warning (disable: 4996)` to get rid of it (surround with `pragma warning (push)`/`pragma warning (pop)`)

Comment: Actually, this is not my code.My professor gave it to me as an component for a C# project ?Let's hope that his code is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shallow search on the web indicates that you are using a deprecated function, raising, thus, the error C4996. As the example presents, you should be using the function _wfopen_s instead.

```
...
// Create an the xml file in text and Unicode encoding mode.
if ((fileHandle = _wfopen( L"_wfopen_test.xml",L"wt+,ccs=UNICODE")) == NULL) // C4996
// Note: _wfopen is deprecated; consider using _wfopen_s instead
{
    wprintf(L"_wfopen failed!\n");
    return(0);
}
...
```

The reason you have this error pointed only once for all of your four calls is that the compiler suppresses repeated errors.

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx

Comment: I use #pragma to disable warning in that header file like Alexandre C wrote above and there is no error in the other header file.I the compiler suppressed error then there should be error in other header.

Comment: Since you told the compiler not to warn you about this deprecation, I guess it shouldn't do it, as it does not.